# AWS Opsworks: logrotate it runs automatically?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cron, aws-opsworks, logrotate

I have configured my own logrotate(app logs) and for editing(nginx logs), all created in a recipes(chef). My question is: logrotate it runs automatically?

*I ask because I have configurations in which the logs can not EXCEED 5MB in size, and have logs with sizes of 100MB.*

show crontabs for root:

```
crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

**/etc/logrotate.conf**

```
weekly
su root syslog
rotate 4
create
include /etc/logrotate.d
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, logrotate is run as a daily cron job. You could add `size 5M` and `daily` to the logrotate config for the logs you're interested in.

There would be the potential for the log to grow past 5M between daily logrotate runs. This could be tuned by lowering the size value and/or running logrotate more often.

Check `man logrotate` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate your files as soon as they get size of 5Mb, just place in `/etc/cron.hourly/` folder executable file with:

```
#!/bin/sh
test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

If that will be not enough you can make a crontab job like this:

`*/30 *  *  *  *   root    logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/nginx`
(for every 30 minutes rotation)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are searching in the wrong place. Logrotate is part of cron daily jobs.

The cron job is in the following directory **"/etc/cron.daily/logrotate"**

You can run the following command to force running the logrotate

```
sudo logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

If you want the logs to be rotated once they reach 5mb, you should add `size` value to your script.

You should have something like this:

```
/var/log/mylogs {
......
missingok
size=5M
create 0664 root utmp
rotate 3
}
```

Here is a [link to more details](http://issamben.com/how-to-setup-up-logroate-with-aws-s3/) on how you can easily setup logrotate.